# SIGABRT Error when trying to switch to second view

Tags: swift, xcode

I want to switch from my main story board to my second view controller.
The code i tried to use is

```
func CountCheck(){
    if rightAnswerCount + wrongAnswerCount == 10{

        let secondViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "secondViewController") as! SecondViewController

        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(secondViewController, animated: true)
    }
}
```

When the rightAnswerCount + wrongAnswerCount == 10, the program crashed and showed the sigabrt error and when i scrolled through the NSLog, it states "reason: 'Storyboard () doesn't contain a view controller with identifier 'SecondViewController''"

There is a view called SecondViewController so i don't understand why it didn't switch to the view, What should i do?

Comment: Please [search on the error](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+doesn%27t+contain+a+view+controller+with+identifier).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Storyboard doesn't contain a view controller with identifier <YourIdentifierName>` error means you didn't set your Storyboard ID to the corresponding name.

1. Go to Storyboard;
2. Open inspector for your View Controller;
3. Set Storyboard ID to `<YourIdentifierName>`.

[image]

Comment: Thank you adding this stopped the crashing, however when rightAnswerCount + wrongAnswerCount == 10, the view didn't change

Comment: That's certainly another question already. Did you create UINavigationController in your storyboard? If not, select your root (first) view controller in storyboard, then go to Xcode menu `Editor -> Embed in -> Navigation Controller`.

Comment: I did, i re-made it and its working like a charm, thank you @nshuman

Comment: @dstaton You're welcome. Feel free to accept the answer if you find it helpful.